# How to create persistence between web and native app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, guid

Is there any way to track UID across web to app on either IOS or Android. For example we have a mobile website which if accessed by a user will remember it. Then they are directed to download the app and when the app is opened, it would be great for the app to know that the user already opened a particular web page on our mobile web site. Without having a login, is it possible to accomplish this? This article seems to "hack" that process? Is there a cleaner way? http://www.hasoffers.com/blog/ios-cookie-tracking-wrong-mobile-app-tracking/